# SQL order with equal group size

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, limit

I have a table with columns `month`, `name` and `transaction_id`. I would like to count the number of transactions per month and name. However, for each month I want to have the top `N` names with the highest transaction counts.

The following query groups by `month` and `name`. However the `LIMIT` is applied to the complete result and not per `month`:

```
SELECT
    month,
    name,
    COUNT(*) AS transaction_count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY month, name
ORDER BY month, transaction_count DESC
LIMIT N
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the top `N` results per `month`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT month, name, transaction_count
FROM (SELECT month, name, COUNT(*) AS transaction_count,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM my_table
      GROUP BY month, name
     ) mn
WHERE seqnum <= N
ORDER BY month, transaction_count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer; exactly what I was looking for :)